# C every value in String array is equal to the last value added

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to analyze a data file with lines of text then add the lines of text to an array of strings using a while loop. It seems that every time I add a new line to the array at the index, every value in the indexes lower than it is set to the string that is being added. For example, if I set strings[2] to value "foo", it also sets strings[1] and strings[0] to "foo", even if the value of strings[1] and strings[0] was something different before.

I've tried testing to see that the values I add to the array are correct, and they are. I've also tried making the array const, with no luck.

```
int main()
{
    char** strings = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    int index = 0;
    StringBundle** bundle = malloc(1000 * sizeof(StringBundle)); //StringBundle is used to parse the string

    while (fgets(str, 500, file))
    {
        bundle[index] = createStringBundle(str); //String bundle works correctly
        char** tokens = bundle[index]->Tokens; //Gets the parts of a parsed string
        char concat[100]; //This string is composed of two parts of the string that is parsed
        strcpy(concat, tokens[1]);
        strcat(concat, tokens[3]);
        printf("%s\n", concat) //This will print the correct value, so the value of concat is correct
        strings[index] = concat;
        index++;
    }
    //"Montery CA" is the last value added to the array
    printf("%s\n", strings[2]); //Issue- this will print "Montery CA", when it should print "Chicago IL"
    printf("%s\n", strings[13]); //Issue- this will print "Montery CA", when it should print "San Diego CA"
}
```

Comment: `strings[index] = concat;` doesn’t do what you think it does...

Comment: May I ask what it does?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for making me think about it Paul(Not being sarcastic). I needed to use strcpy instead of = to set the strings[index] to concat.

Comment: For starters, it's seems like you don't understand the meaning of this line: `char** strings = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));`. As a matter of fact you're trying here to create an **array** of **pointers** to **char**. Since that, you need to allocate memory for required quantity of pointers to char, not for chars itself: `malloc(1000 * sizeof(char*))`. And so on, with `StringBundle**` and further.

Comment: Additionally you need to allocate memory for each pointer `string[i]`. Otherwise they are uninitialized and don't point to any valid memory.